# Support for Azure Active Directory Authentication in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

How can i achieve the `azure active directory Universal With MFA` authentication in Liquibase? is it supported? If supported, What will be the URL format?

I used following `url --url="jdbc:sqlserver://some.database.windows.net,1433;Database=myDB;Authentication=Azure Active Directory Universal With MFA;"`  But i got the following exception :

liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The authentication value "azure active directory universal with mfa" is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Active Directory with MFA isn't currently supported by the Microsoft JDBC drivers: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1053

Given that Liquibase depends on JDBC, it looks like it's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is out-of-date. The latest mssql-jdbc drivers do support MFA.

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication

For example, using JDBC URI:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydatabase;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated
```